# how to store the coding of output of D3.js in database

Tags: javascript, database, d3.js, data-visualization

I am making a application with the help of D3.js. I just started working on it and I got stuck.

**Problem**: I want to store that coding that made by visualization with the help of d3.js( for example pie chart) in to my database.

Again I just want to store the coding that made by output of d3.js pie chart in to database.

I tried some things like to make the output in particular sector on page and then copy it. but its not working.

If can suggest me, it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: can you give a more specific example of what you want to save to the database. Is it SVG paths or something?

Comment: This is the basic example of pie chart

http://jsbin.com/acatof/3/edit?html,output

If can see the background coding through "view source" then you can get a new calculated code for svg. I want to store that code in database.